# Is there a way to find what types of aircraft have landed at an airport?

Tags: airport, aviation-history

When I was a child, I recall an aircraft landing at my local airport, [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus_Metropolitan_Airport_(Georgia)), I would like to know if airports keep records of what aircraft land there? If so how long do they keep these records, and are the available to the public?

Comment: Unless the flight is a historic one, typically the only data that gets recorded is the number of arrivals/departures based on aircraft weight/category. A lot of times these things are estimated and not actual values. So at least in the U.S., no record is kept that associates an aircraft registration number (specific aircraft) with arrivals and departures. Sometimes these are kept for airlines for billing purposes (landing fees), I don't know of any public source for that data though. See https://www.airnav.com/airport/KGRB for an example (scroll down to Operational Statistics).

Comment: @RonBeyer You could find data for a good number of flights into major airports on flight-tracking sites, those are only around for a day or two though since they get buried by the other flights coming in.

Comment: A lot of small airports do have a "guest book" that pilots will often sign. The ones I have seen usually only go back a few years, but old copies of the guest book are probably kept. Such records are entirely voluntary.

Comment: Are you talking about a type of aircraft or a specific plane? Something that landed there once or was it a recurring flight?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple answer... No. You could rule out the types of planes that could land at an airport by an [airport's 5010](http://www.gcr1.com/5010web/) but there is nothing specific.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for the US, airports only report total movements (landings/takeoffs) and this information is available to the public via the FAA. This information is in aggregate and does not contain the type of aircraft.

[Flightaware](http://flightaware.com/) tracks only the *type* of aircrafts that land and takeoff at an airport; it also tracks the identifier used. It has very good coverage globally, although some areas have better (more accurate) information than others.

For most GA flights, the identifier is sometimes also the tail number, which can then be used to narrow down on a specific airframe.

Just add the ICAO identifier for your aerodome at the end of this URL: `http://flightaware.com/live/airport/` to see stats of a particular aiport; for your airport its http://flightaware.com/live/airport/KCSG